# angular ng-if numerical boolean

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I'm having a bit of trouble getting Angular ng-if to work. I want one of my DOM elements to disappear when $scope.week = 1.

In my controller I've set

```
$scope.week = 1
```

In my markup I have

```
<span class="prev" ng-if="{{week}} !== 1"></span>
```

Does anyone know how to get boolean conditionals to evaluate in ng-if? Thanks!

Comment: ng-if has access to scope; you don't need {{ }} around your variable `week`

Comment: it looks like that results in a string literal ng-if="week != 1" though?

Comment: You can do that or `!==` for type comparison. I added a jsfiddle to my answer.

Comment: Very similar question asked here: ng-if [Angular ng-if does not evaluate conditional statement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23937416/1959948)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the {{ }} from `week` variable. Ng-if accesses scope objects without the braces.

```
<span class="prev" ng-if="week !== 1"></span>
```

See the documentation on [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) for more examples.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Enprj/), and a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8sv5M/) with a toggle function.

Comment: thanks! I didn't catch the extra {{}} around my variable. It also turns out that I was on a version of angular that predates ng-if, so now I'm all good to go

Comment: Ahh, I forgot to mention the version issue. Good catch. Unrelated: Thank you for giving me `1337` reputation.